# Geometry construction exercise

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I have another construction Problem.

What is given is a point A and two streight lines f and g. One should construct a Rhombus ABCD with side lenght 4cm. B should be on f and his midpoint on g.

See Picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxOIq.jpg)

So far I drawed a circle of ray 4cm centered in A. So one of the two intersections with f has to be B. The second cirrcle is also of 4 cm starting from one of the two intersection points (since all the sides have to be the same lenght. But this attempt is not really walid since you cant be sure wich of the two intersections is bin the first place).

Can someone see how to get the Rhombus from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the red circle! and mark $B$ on $f$. Draw the green circle and mark $M$.
$AM$ and $BM$ are the half diagonals of your rhombus.
Of course point $N$ can also be another solution.
[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution ! Could you explain to me why you find M by drawing the small green circle?

Comment: $AB=4cm$ is the diameter of the green circle, $M$ is the intersection of the green circle and the line $g$. And we know that inscribed angles subtended by a diameter are right angles. And we also know that the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: ooooh ! so good ! yes see it now ! awesome ! thank you very much !

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose the solution initially following your  sketch.

[image]